# Django HttpResponse - open file object in default editor

Tags: django, windows, httpresponse

Take the following code snippet of a Django view

```
def serve_file(request)
    path = 'C:/path_to_file/test.html'
    file_name = os.path.basename(path)
    response = HttpResponse(path)
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={0}'.format(file_name)
    return response
```

The file is served in the response and the browser asks do I want to open, but when it opens in the default editor, it opens from 'Temporary INternet Files'. How can I have this open from its original location at 'C:/path_to_file/'?

Answer (score 2):

There's a fundamental disconnect here. When Django serves the file, even if it's on your own computer, the browser has to download it before it can be accessed. So the actual file that would be opened is not at the original `C:/...` location, but in whatever directory the file was downloaded to.

If you need users of your website to be able to edit files that persist on your server, that will require much more work than this. Downloading a file creates a copy of it on the user's computer.